# PUT request to https site keeps returning status: 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, put

I'm trying to make a PUT request to plug.dj with a httpWebRequest in c#, the problem i'm having is that i keep getting error 400(bad Request) but the request i made looks the same as the original one, am i misisng something?

These are the request headers that i got from chrome when i go to the network tab:

```
PUT /_/booth/lock HTTP/1.1
Host: plug.dj
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: https://plug.dj
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://plug.dj/ao3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: {Left out becouse it's used to authenticate}
```

The request payload and the request Url:

```
{"isLocked":true,"removeAllDJs":false}
https://plug.dj/_/booth/lock
```

And this is the one i created in c# using httpWebRequest(the authentication is correct so that's not the error):

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

httpWebRequest.Accept                           = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"]       = "gzip, deflate, sdch";
httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"]       = "nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength                    = data.Length;
httpWebRequest.Headers["Cookie"]                = GetCookies();
httpWebRequest.Host                             = "plug.dj";
httpWebRequest.Headers["Origin"]                = "https://plug.dj";
httpWebRequest.Referer                          = "https://plug.dj/" + _room;
httpWebRequest.UserAgent                        = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36";
httpWebRequest.Headers["X-Requested-With"]      = "XMLHttpRequest";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Try using Fiddler to see what the request from your c# program looks like.

Comment: I tried using Fiddler @MårtenWikström, when i ran my program this showed up in Fiddler: "CONNECT plug.dj:443 HTTP/1.1" right after that in my c# code the error: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Edit: When i supress the ssl error, i get a status 400: Bad Request again.. (ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };)

Comment: Either try to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, or enable support for decrypting HTTPS traffic in Fiddler:

http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: Using HTTP doesn't work, and the decrypting trows an error: "The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided." I really don't have experience with ssl

Comment: Ok. I think seeing the request sent from your c# program and comparing that to the request from Chrome is cruical in finding out why you receive 400 Bad Request. However, I'm afraid I can't help you out with configuring SSL decryption in Fiddler as I've never done it myself.